# Memory management without stack?

Tags: recursion, fortran, stack, allocation

To model the run-time semantics of procedures, it is known that a stack is generally needed. 
If the language does not allow procedure recursion, do we have to have stacks?
And if the language does allow procedure recursion, but a recursive call can only happen at the end of a procedure, do we have to have stacks?

Answer (score 1):

In Fortran, which you are probably interested in as an example, you do need stack for recursion. It is because you want local variables of recursive procedures to be independent for each invocation of the procedure. Not all have to be independent, but you generally want to have this possibility.

Without recursion, you have only one  invocation of any procedure at any time so local variables can be static. Not so with recursion, you don't know how deep it will be so you need some dynamic data structure to store the data. You could emulate the stack on the heap if necessary, but you do need some dynamic memory.

Often, stack is also used for automatic (variable length) arrays, but that is not required, they can be on the heap depending on the compiler and its settings.

Answer (score 0):

Stack is used to store return address to reach after a method ends execution.
Stack is also used to allocate objects with limited duration scope.

So, if your launguage does not permit automatic (C style) objects (or in other words, does not permit local scopes) or does not permit methods, I suppose language could omit stack implementation completely.

I think recursion doesn't have anything to do with requirement of stack.